# How can I import an evolution email directory onto a new computer?

Tags: email, backup, import, evolution

I have a backup of the hard drive of a system that got messed up and could no longer load a window manager. I'm trying to import the data from it to a new computer, and I am stuck at the point of making evolution work. I tried rsyncing the data into place in `.local/share/evolution` but it doesn't appear to be recognized on the new system. I know evolution normally has a nice backup procedure available, however I don't have access to the original install to make that work.

The version of evolution I'm using is 3.8.4. I don't for sure know what version the old one was, but it would've been quite recent.

Can anyone suggest a process for getting access to this email data?

Answer (score 1):

I am working with Evolution 3.22.6 on Kubuntu 16.10. I transfered `data\setting`s from close version of Evolution on Kubuntu 16.04 LTS.

First, install Evolution itself.

Second, copy folders `/home/%user%/.local/share/evolution/`, `/home/%user%/.cache/evolution/` and `/home/%user%/.config/evolution/` from old user folder to new.

This got me all of my mails and setting besides my IMAP account password.

Answer (score 0):

Evolution has an "import" feature (in the file menu) that you can use in this case. Your `.local/share/evolution` folder should contain a bunch of `.mbox` files and the like that can be imported.

Also, I think you could find [this thread on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859630) useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found an old properly exported backup. I tried importing it, and then rsyncing the directory structure overtop to get the most up to date emails. This turned out to work, but it's definitely not a thing I'd rely on.